# mySQL pattern matching a comma separated list

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a mySQL table that contains restaurant information. Part of that information is a comma separated list of numbers that corresponds to the type of cuisine the restaurant serves. I'm having some problems getting the correct information out of the database. Table looks like

```
id businessName cuisine_id
1  Pizza Place  2,3,4,
2  Burger Place 12,13,14,
```

I came up with

```
SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE cuisine_id LIKE "%2,%"
```

But that leaves me with the problem that it matches "2," "12," and 22,".

I also tried

```
SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE cuisine_id LIKE "[^0-9]2,%"
```

But that returned nothing.

Any advice on how to write this expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `regexp`

```
SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE cuisine_id REGEXP "(^|,)2,"
```

For num exact match,

```
SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE cuisine_id regexp "(^|,)2(,|$)"
```

Note that `^`, `$` are mentioned as regex anchors which matches the start and end end of a line. This `(^|,)` will match either a start of a line or comma. So this ensured that the following pattern must be at the start or preceeded by comma.

Comment: good solution, but I was thinking that he should change his db structure, because saving all the ids in 1 table is not good. I would also suggest to go and normailze (and make use of relations) his db.

Comment: Thanks Avinash, worked perfectly.
Davejal, as you and fthiella pointed out this may not be the best way to store this data. I will start working on normalizing the database. This isn't the only place where I could benefit from better use of relations. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use regular expressions, you could use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) string function:

```
SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', cuisine_id)>0
```

or use CONCAT:

```
SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE CONCAT(',', cuisine_id, ',') LIKE '%,2,%'
```

or better to normalize your database structure (is often not a good idea to store comma separated values in a single field)